# Learning Image Processing from Scratch

Tags: image-processing

I am currently a Junior going for my Computer Science degree. I am really curious about how things actually work. While I realize that I will never understand everything there is to know about everything, I would love to dive into the basics of a lot of things. There are a lot of such things that I have encountered for my day to day life: machine learning, AI, servers, compilers, etc. However, something that truly amazes me is image process software and the amazing things we have achieved with it to this date.

It seems, however, that no matter where I look, I am not getting a lot insight into how it works, but rather a list of libraries to use (*cough* OpenCV) instead. While it is great that libraries like this exists, using it defeats the purpose of wanting to learn how things work.

Is there any good resource that someone could recommend regarding image processing or is the best choice I have is to look through existing libraries?

Comment: check these free courses https://www.coursera.org/learn/image-processing/ https://www.udacity.com/course/introduction-to-computer-vision--ud810

Comment: I'd recommend just buying any well-known image processing book and work through that, there are plenty. Other than that maybe there is a comp. science university near you where you could sign up as a guest student for any image processing class. It is definitely a wise choice to start with the basics and trying to understand the process instead of reading random OpenCV python blogs (of which there are **a lot**).

Comment: You can probably start by taking signal (1 to nd) processing and machine learning courses online or in your college.  I would also recommend getting comfortable with python and c++.  If you are interested in computer vision, it is probably good to have both conventional image processing and machine learning knowledge. Probably the best way to start this is by finding a project or a paper that you are interested in and try to replicate the result (for the latter).

Comment: First take some classes in Image processing. Buy a book, if you do not take classes. You do not have to know any formal software language to learn image processing. You can get experience from tools that are already built, such as ImageMagick or Matlab, etc. Try to process images from the concepts given in the books or classes using whatever tools or language you know or like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user T A recommend, buy a good undergraduate-level book about image processing and work your way through it.

Gonzalez and Woods is a commonly used textbook, and you should find it readable.

https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Gonzalez-Digital-Image-Processing-4th-Edition/PGM241219.html

How you approach learning the field depends on what learning style you’ve found most effective in the past.

1. Pick a relatively simple image processing problem, such as counting the number of circles in an image. FIRST, try to solve it yourself. Give that a day or two. Then, if you’re stuck, look for answers in your textbook.

   2. Find a free OpenCV course. At first, try to solve some problems by treating the algorithms (the OpenCV functions) as black boxes: read the documentation, tinker with parameters, try different images, etc., but don’t dig into the algorithms too deeply until you have some sense how the algorithms can be used together at a high level.
   3. Take an undergraduate course. Having a professor or instructor lead you through problems, and the need to make a grade, can help motivation if it sags.
   4. Get an internship at a company that uses image processing in its products. Take ANY internship remotely related to code, then as appropriate ask engineers how things work, what to read, etc.

As a rule, I don’t recommend learning image processing piecemeal reading blogs, etc.

The more you try to solve practical problems on your own, the more you’ll appreciate some of the less appreciated problems in the field. Choosing the right camera, lightening, and other hardware choices becomes important as you try to make an image processing system work more robustly. Many demos you see online won’t work well in real-world situations. (For example, distinguishing objects by their expected color can lead to disappointing results even if the lighting, distance to the object, and orientation of the object change only slightly.)

Above all, try to find some particular problem that interests you: identifying animals; SLAM; facial recognition; predicting events based on video streams; determining the ripeness of fruit; or whatever. Try to find some aspect of image processing that overlaps some other interest of yours: sports, literature, music, theater, social networks, bike racing, animal husbandry, environmental science, or what have you. Once you’ve identified a problem of interest, tackle is problems of increasingly greater complexity.

And if you have more questions, feel free to send me a private message. I’ve been in the field for over two decades, and I like helping steer new folks into the field.

Also: you can get started with Python, Julia, or any of several other languages, but it’s still (as of 2019) common for image processing algorithms to be written in C or C++. So I’d suggest starting with the language you know and like the best, but spend some time practicing C++ as well. Most of the academic papers I read provide algorithms in C or C++, though typically in older style C++ that doesn’t require you to be familiar with C++11 and later.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and resources to acquire. I will be looking into this!

Comment: I would love to send you a message and get in contact. What would be a good medium to do so?

Comment: I created a chat and gave you read/write privileges: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96766/image-processing-career-chat

It may be a full day between each time I check SO, but I'll follow up when I can.